# Is there a way to speed up the conversion of spark dataframe to pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I tried to convert spark dataframe to pandas in databricks notebook with pyspark. It takes for ever running. Is there a better way to do this? There are more than 600,000 rows.

`df_PD = sparkDF.toPandas()`

`df_PD = sparkDF.toPandas()`

Comment: check if you can emulate `pandas` behavior by means of `spark` functionality first

Answer (score 2):

Can you try changing your import statement and importing the [Pandas API for Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/pandas_pyspark.html)?

```
import pyspark.pandas as pd
df_PD = sparkDF.to_pandas()
```